# How to use QStringView with QML?

Tags: string, qt, qt5, qstring

I am trying to understand how/if I can use `QStringView` in signal/slots that are called from QML. For example, in the below code, can I use `QStringView` instead of `QString`?

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString priority READ priority WRITE setPriority NOTIFY priorityChanged)
```

From what I am reading from the documentation, any type that is supported by `QVariant` can be used in a `Q_PROPERTY`, I can understand why `QStringView` is not supported by QVariant but I am looking for a way to use `QStringView` with QML, instead of passing `QString` copies between the two all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported conversions between QML and C++ data types are described in [this document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html).

The supported data types could be split into four categories:

- Basic datatypes
- `QObject` derived classes (ex. `QAbstractItemModel`)
- Some basic lists
- Enumerations

**Answer:**`QStringView` is not part of any of these categories. So, it is not possible to transfer it to QML.

**Possible workaround:** You could try to create a `QObject` based wrapper around `QStringView`, which implements the desired QML interface.